# Tell script to continue sequential formula in Google Sheet columns after inserting new rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet where I want one column to continue down a simple sequential formula all the way down like so:
[image: sequential numbering]

The formula in each cell is simply starting with "1" in B2 and continuing `=B2+1`,`=B3+1`, `=B4+1`, etc. all the way down.
[Link to my test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tIYnuJU1t3tl0kk4nTqNB7zj4ndXM6R2PpujDao8Uwc/edit#gid=0)

I have a script connected that will insert new rows, but it leaves the new cells in this column blank, while I want to continue the formula pattern from top to bottom, wherever I end up adding new rows, which will be different every time.

I'm stumped on how to do this as I'm not very versed in writing these Apps Scripts. My best guess is below adapted from a similar question I came across online, but it does not work in my sheet:

```js
function FillFormulas() {   

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Input');   

var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();   

spreadsheet.getRange("B2").setFormula("=B1+1");   
var fillDownRange = spreadsheet.getRange(2,2,(lastRow-1));   spreadsheet.getRange("B2").copyTo(fillDownRange); 
}
```

Any tips appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should consider using a formula that automatically expands to the bottom of the sheet. You can use the [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en) function for example.

Comment: If you definitely want the formula to be copied all the way down, you could try getMaxRows() instead of getLastRow()

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative Options

> *I agree with the comments made by [@ztiaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17887301/ztiaa) that `SEQUENCE` is the most efficient method to approach this.*

Based on your question, you want to retain the sequence of numbers in column B even if new rows have been added. However, if you have a specific use case for using the custom formula `=B2+1` on every row and if your question has been misunderstood, kindly update your post accordingly for clarity.

Aside from using `SEQUENCE`, there are other ways as well, though not as efficient. Such as using the `ARRAYFORMULA`.

***E.g.***
`=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(B2:B)-1)`

### *Demo*

***Placed the function on column `B` row `2`***
[image]

### *Other methods via scripting*

> *I have also tried tweaking your script below.*

### ***Tweaked Script Version 1***

What this script does is, after it runs, it will manipulate the values in column `B` & ***add new sequential numbers accordingly***.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var editedValue = e.value
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet()
  var editedCell = editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, editedCol)
  var editedSheetName = editedSheet.getName()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited value = "+editedValue+", edited row = "+editedRow+", edited column = "+editedCol)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited sheet name = "+editedSheet.getName()+", the edited cell Range = "+editedCell.getA1Notation())

  // test for edit on sheet:"Input", in Column:A and value:"tiger"
  if (editedSheetName !== "Input" || editedCol !== 1 || editedValue !== "tiger") {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: INVALID edit: sheet <> input &/or col <> 1 &/or value <>tiger")
    return
  } else {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: VALID edit: sheet = input & col = 1 & value =tiger")
    // insert blank rows
    editedSheet.insertRowsAfter(editedRow, 3);
    // insert process description steps (2 columns to the right)
    var steps = [["has stripes"], ["is orange and black"], ["has sharp teeth"]]
    var person = [["pattern checker"], ["color checker"], ["teeth checker"]]
    var shapes = [["Start"], ["Start"], ["Start"]]
    editedCell.offset(1, 2, 3).setValues(steps)
    editedCell.offset(1, 6, 3).setValues(person)
    editedCell.offset(1, 5, 3).setValues(shapes)
    // delete validation for the new rows
    editedSheet.getRange(3, 1, 3).setDataValidation(null)
  }

  //If you want to retain sequence numbers in your sheet in column B
  var newValues = editedSheet.getDataRange().getValues().map((row,index) => index == 0 ? row : row.map((column, i) => i == 1 ? index : column));
  editedSheet.getDataRange().setValues(newValues);

}
```

### *Demo*

[image]

### ***Tweaked Script Version 2***

After this script runs, it will manipulate the values in column `B` & ***set new formulas accordingly***.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var editedValue = e.value
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet()
  var editedCell = editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, editedCol)
  var editedSheetName = editedSheet.getName()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited value = "+editedValue+", edited row = "+editedRow+", edited column = "+editedCol)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited sheet name = "+editedSheet.getName()+", the edited cell Range = "+editedCell.getA1Notation())

  // test for edit on sheet:"Input", in Column:A and value:"tiger"
  if (editedSheetName !== "Input" || editedCol !== 1 || editedValue !== "tiger") {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: INVALID edit: sheet <> input &/or col <> 1 &/or value <>tiger")
    return
  } else {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: VALID edit: sheet = input & col = 1 & value =tiger")
    // insert blank rows
    editedSheet.insertRowsAfter(editedRow, 3);
    // insert process description steps (2 columns to the right)
    var steps = [["has stripes"], ["is orange and black"], ["has sharp teeth"]]
    var person = [["pattern checker"], ["color checker"], ["teeth checker"]]
    var shapes = [["Start"], ["Start"], ["Start"]]
    editedCell.offset(1, 2, 3).setValues(steps)
    editedCell.offset(1, 6, 3).setValues(person)
    editedCell.offset(1, 5, 3).setValues(shapes)
    // delete validation for the new rows
    editedSheet.getRange(3, 1, 3).setDataValidation(null)
  }

  //If you want to retain thesequence numbers via "formula" in your sheet column B
  var fomulas = editedSheet.getDataRange().getValues().map((row,index) => index != 0 && row.map((_,i) => i == 1 && `B${index}+1`).filter(x => x)).filter(y => y);
  editedSheet.getRange(`B1`).setValue(0);//Added this line  for the formula to NOT break.
  editedSheet.getRange(`B2:B${editedSheet.getLastRow()}`).setFormulas(fomulas);

}
```

### *Demo*

[image]

### *Reference*

- [Apps Script `setFormulas()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)